# 401 Unauthorized when requesting Bing Text to Speech API

Tags: python, text-to-speech, bing-api

I am using this example from Azure-Samples github. 
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Cognitive-Speech-TTS/blob/master/Samples-Http/Python/TTSSample.py

I replaced the api key with my own, but I am getting 401 errors.

Here is the response code and reply from the API.

```
401 Unauthorized
Response text:  b''
```

Here are the paths I am using:

```
token_host = "api.cognitive.microsoft.com"
token_path = "/sts/v1.0/issueToken"
speech_host = "westus.tts.speech.microsoft.com"
speech_path = "/cognitiveservices/v1"
```

[image]

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Hi! Did you resolve this issue?  I'm experiencing the same problem with environment which was working fine before..

Comment: @zo_chu Had the same issues. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem and it appears that the correct API is NOT

> https://westus.tts.speech.microsoft.com/cognitiveservices/v1

but

> https://speech.platform.bing.com/synthesize

Comment: this is interesting. I will try this, I've been having this issue for a week now.

Comment: In my case it is the exact opposite. I can only make it work with `https://westus.tts.speech.microsoft.com/cognitiveservices/v1`and NOT with `https://speech.platform.bing.com/synthesize`although the API documentation states different.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same 401 issues. I switched regions, tried various endpoints to no avail.

Got it working with this code:

```
import requests

key = "< YOUR API KEY GOES HERE >"
headers = {
    'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Length': '0',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': key,
}

res = requests.post('https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issuetoken', headers=headers)
print(res.status_code)
token = res.content.decode("utf-8")

fileformat = "audio-16khz-128kbitrate-mono-mp3" 

lang = "en-US"
gender = "Male"
voice = "Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (en-US, BenjaminRUS)"
text = "This is a sample text, that Benjamin will speak."

headers = { "Content-type" : "application/ssml+xml",
            "X-Microsoft-OutputFormat" : fileformat,
            "User-Agent" : "TTSForPython",
            "Authorization" : "Bearer " + token, 
            }

body = f"<speak version='1.0' xml:lang='{lang}'><voice xml:lang='{lang}' xml:gender='{gender}' name='{voice}'>{text}</voice></speak>"

res = requests.post('https://westus.tts.speech.microsoft.com/cognitiveservices/v1', headers=headers, data=body)
print(res.status_code)

audiofile = res.content

with open("file.mp3", "wb") as f:
    f.write(audiofile)
```